# Cleaning up a shape in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am working on a character and the mouth looks like this so far:

[image]

My problem: The upper and lower teeth booth go beyond the black part. My goal is to neaten the mouth up so that it has a linear form and no parts stick out into the brown part as the teeth do now.

My idea was to take the black shape, copy it in front and somehow to achieve that all parts outside the shape's form vanish. I just want to neat up the mouth. But I haven't found out how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by selecting the mouth, and copy/paste it on top of the teeth. Select the newly copied mouth and the teeth, right click and select "Make Clipping Mask".

This will create a mask that hides the parts of the teeth that are outside of the mouth. The advantage of this is that you can nudge the teeth and still keep them "inside" the mouth. To get access to the teeth, double click the mouth to "go inside" the Clipping Mask.

You can also use Path Finder tools, they will cut the edges of the teeth (instead of hiding them as the Clipping Mask will do). The Minus Front under Path Finder will probably do what you need :)